# Opening browser from emacs script?

Tags: elisp

I have the following emacs lisp snippet that will launch my browser from within emacs and open the specified pages.  However when I run it as a script from a shell nothing happens.  What more do I need to do?  I tried dropping (interactive).

```
#!/usr/bin/emacs --script

(defun surf-news ()
  (interactive)
  (progn
    (browse-url "http://news.ycombinator.com")
    (browse-url "http://stackoverflow.com")
      ))

(surf-news)
```

Comment: That script works for me... on Windows even (cygwin).

Comment: I tried on a Mac and on OpenSolaris.  Maybe I'm missing a config value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A neat function I discovered yesterday is M-x webjump which has recently been added to emacs.

Answer (score 1):

As Ryan Thompson mentioned above, you can use xdg-open in Emacs.
Change:

```
(browse-url "http://news.ycombinator.com")
(browse-url "http://stackoverflow.com")
```

To:

```
(browse-url-xdg-open "http://news.ycombinator.com")
(browse-url-xdg-open "http://stackoverflow.com"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on this [site](http://members.shaw.ca/akochoi-emacs), at the bottom, where it describes a Mac OS pty bug.  I had to add this line and a slight delay between urls.

```
 (setq process-connection-type nil)
```

Here's the complete solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/emacs --script

(setq process-connection-type nil);; pty's broken on the Mac

(defun surf ()
  (progn
    (browse-url "http://news.ycombinator.com")
    (sleep-for 0.5);  We need a delay
    (browse-url "http://stackoverflow.com")
    ))
;;
;; This is what's going on behind the scenes
;;(setq url "http://www.google.com")
;;(start-process (concat "open " url) nil "open" url)

(surf)
```

Answer (score 0):

On linux, if you are in GNOME, KDE, or probably almost any graphical environment, there is probably a command called `xdg-open`. This command basically takes its argument and opens it with the desktop default application. It handles both files and URLs. So generally when I need to say "Open this in the default application," I use `xdg-open`.

I think Mac OS has a similar command just called `open`.